# what is a good text editor for ubuntu touch?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, software-recommendation, ubuntu-touch, vim

I have ubuntu touch installed on an arm based andriod phone.
I have some files to edit, but using vim and nano is hard using the onscreen keyboard since I haven't figured out how to press the escape key, or how to press ctrl+x. Im wondering what a better text editor would be.

I have been using `echo "stuff" > filename` which works ok for short edits. I'm just looking for a better way to edit files where the keyboard is a touch screen.

Comment: For a temp work around, I iinstalled openssh-server, and now can ssh in with my regular computer to edit files.

Comment: As sad as it is, Ubuntu Touch is **not [on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)** on AU.

Comment: @dessert I think the meta question [How should we handle new and future questions about Ubuntu Touch?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17252) is more helpful than the on-topic link, in this case.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed off topic, but rather "primarily opinion based" as it's asking a subjective question. Or it could be focused more on how to use text based tools in the Terminal app on Ubuntu Touch.

Comment: @j0h for what it's worth, ssh is already available on Ubuntu Touch. You just need to run `android-gadget-service ssh enable` to enable it, then you can ssh to the device over WiFi.

Comment: yeah ssh is probably what I'll end up using mostly. typing on a touch screen is a pain in the butt, llike anything that needs a ctrl+command key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tedit seems to have large menu options etc that could be useful for a touch device: https://open-store.io/app/tedit.fulvio

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1015015)

Comment: @David Even without the link, it would be clear that this answer is recommending Tedit and why, so I don't think this is a link-only answer. The question is asking for software recommendations, which this provides. *Callumpy*: With that said, I do recommend expanding this with more details about the software.